# Angular - ngResource with fallback urls

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, fallback

is there a way to create a $resource with multiple urls that are used as chained fallbacks? So instead of returning an error when the host is not reachable on the first url, the resource tries sending the request to the second url and so forth.

Thanks for any ideas,

Jensen

Answer (score 0):

This function wraps the $ngResource and takes the last parameter(array of callbacks [{success,error}, {success,error}] and loops through each using promise.

```js
//using lodash
function ngResourceWrapper() {
    var args = _.toArray(arguments);
    var callbacks = _.last(args); 
    if (_.isArray(callbacks)) {
      args.splice(args.length - 1, 1); //remove last element
    }
    var promise = $ngResouce.apply($ngResouce, args).promise;

    if (callbacks) {
      callbacks
        .forEach(function(callback) {
            promise
              .then(callbacks.success, callbacks.error);
          }

        }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Does this do what you want?

```
$ngResource.get(url).then(success, useFallbackUrl);

function useFallbackUrl(){ // you can also store these somewhere
    $ngResource.get(url2).then(success);
}

function success(){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Instead of specifying a fallback on each and every request i hope to hide the retry logic. So the resource can be constructed like this - $resource([ url, fallback1, fallback2, fallbackN ], /* other ngResource parameters */);